# tensorflow sequence to sequence models error

Tags: tensorflow

I am getting the following errors after executing translate.py from sequence to sequence models tutorial in tensorflow[image]

Can anyone please help me in resolving this error
Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of tensorflow do you have?

Comment: My tensorflow version is 0.12.1

Comment: Does this still happen with 1.0? I know GRUCell was moved to contrib in 1.0 so if your version is older but the tutorial is newer something could break.

Comment: I upgraded to 1.0 but it did not work. I was suggested to install tensorflow from sources, I tried but it gave me error. Did you execute sequence to sequence models tutorial?